# Javascript returning 'undefined' if i have less than one element in the form.

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

In the following example:

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function checkcheckboxElem(checkboxElem)
{
    alert ("checkboxElem " + checkboxElem.length);  

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="checkForm">
        Master: <input type="checkbox" name="master" value="6694" onclick="checkcheckboxElem(document.checkForm.checkboxElem)"><br>

        Child1: <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxElem" value="2">
    </form>                             
</body>
```

The alert outputs 'undefined'. For some reason it does this if there is only one checkbox. If i add another checkbox then it outputs the correct length. If i change it as shown below then it outputs 2

```
<html>
<head>
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
function checkcheckboxElem(checkboxElem)
{
    alert ("checkboxElem " + checkboxElem.length);  

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="checkForm">
        Master: <input type="checkbox" name="master" value="6694" onclick="checkcheckboxElem(document.checkForm.checkboxElem)"><br>

        Child1: <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxElem" value="2">
Child2: <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxElem" value="1">
    </form>
```

Why does it return 'undefined' if it is only one checkbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case `document.checkForm.checkboxElem` refers to a single input element, in the second case it refers to an array of input elements. You could do:

```
function checkcheckboxElem(checkboxElem) {
    if(!checkboxElem.length)
        checkboxElem = [checkboxElem];
    alert ("checkboxElem " + checkboxElem.length);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks - are you creating an array at line 3?

Comment: Yeah, so from there on you are always dealing with an array. Should probably rename the variable though :) If it's just the length you are interested in what @ManseUK suggests above is cleaner.

Comment: Yes i am interested on the length so that i can do some further processing. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It returns `undefined` because there is only a single element - javascript does not treat this as an array so it has no length property .... you could use this to ensure you always have a length :

```
var len = checkboxElem.length;
if(len == undefined) len = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case it reffers directly to the checkbox element and it has no *length* property. In the second case, there are multiple elements with the same name, so it returns an array of corresponding elements.

To get array of elements use

```
document.getElementsByName('checkboxElem');
```

Answer (score 1):

It returns the number of elements found, instead of the value of one..

The output 2 isn't the value of one of the boxes.. It's the amount of elements..

use something like checkboxElem.val()

Comment: Yes i am interested in the length not the values.

Comment: Ok, if only 1 element is found, it doens't return an array, so the .length method doesnt work..

Answer (score 1):

beacuse in first case

```
document.checkForm.checkboxElem
```

is specific element, but if there are more elements with same name it is array - try this

```
alert ("checkboxElem " + ( typeof( checkboxElm.length ) == 'undefined' ? 1 : checkboxElem.length ));
```